# Why does this function work but give me a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

```
.code32
.text


.globl _start
_start:

;  .globl main
  .extern printf

  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
;  subl $4, %esp

  movl 4(%ebp), %eax 
;  movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
 ; movl $0, %ecx

  cmp $2, %eax
  jne argCount  

  pushl %eax
  pushl $msg2
  call printf
  add $8, %esp

  movl %ebp, %esp
  popl %ebp

;  movl $1, %eax
 ; movl $0, %ebx
 ; int $0x80
  call exit

argCount:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp

  pushl $msg3
  call printf
  add $4, %esp

  movl %ebp, %esp
  popl %ebp

  ret


.data

;  .asciz "Arg = %s"
  msg2: .asciz "Arg Count = %d\n"
  msg3: .asciz "This program takes 1 argument -> sizeOfArray\n"
```

Why does function argCount get correctly executed if the argument count on the command line is not equal to 2 but give me a segmentation fault? The overall control flow of the program seems to be working correctly otherwise. Perhaps there is something wrong with the function prologue or epilogue?

Comment: You use `jne` to branch to a function `argCount` instead of a `call`. Combined with the fact that you did not use `main` (which is also wrong), that will lead to a crash. Actually it will crash even with `main` because the return address is not at that location on the stack.

Comment: jne is correct because I only want argCount to execute if the value in eax is not equal to 2.

Comment: It's not correct because you can't `jne` to a function (except under special circumstances). Either make it a label inside your current function, or rewrite the code so that you can `call` it.

Comment: How do you create label?

Comment: Why is there a `.code32` directive? Make sure you aren' assembling in 64 bit mode. To crete  label, begin a line with `labelname:` where `labelname` is the name of the label you want to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the `ret` at the end of `argCount` goes to the wrong place because it doesn't have a valid return address.

Furthermore, you should use `main` if you intend to work with libc, and also be careful to maintain required stack alignment as per the ABI. Using a frame pointer is optional and doesn't usually help with anything, so I have omitted it.

Here is a possible version:

```
  .globl main
main:                 # main because we use libc
  subl $12, %esp      # stack alignment
  movl 16(%esp), %eax # argc
  cmpl $2, %eax
  movl $msg3, (%esp)  # preset for msg3
  jne argCount        # if argc!=2 use that
  movl $msg2, (%esp)  # otherwise msg2
  movl %eax, 4(%esp)  # and argc
argCount:
  call printf         # print
  call exit           # exit

.data
  msg2: .asciz "Arg Count = %d\n"
  msg3: .asciz "This program takes 1 argument -> sizeOfArray\n"
```

Be sure to compile and link using `gcc` so that libc is pulled in properly, and supply `-m32` if you are on a 64 bit environment to produce 32 bit program (because this code only works as 32 bit).

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
cmp $2, %eax
jne argCount
```

`CALL` does two things:

1. Push the return address onto the stack
2. Jump unconditionally to the called function.

If you use a `Jcc` or `JMP` instruction to call a function, you will need to  manually push the return address onto the stack for your code to work properly.

```
push return_address
jmp argCount
return_address:
```

This is going to cause problems if you are using a conditional jump however, since when you're writing the code you can't predict whether or not the branch was taken (and therefore the `RET` in the called function already popped the return address off the stack for you, or you need to take care of that yourself).

What you should be doing is:

```
cmp $2, %eax
je skip_argcount_call
call argCount
skip_argcount_call:
```